# Where exactly is the dcos src directory on github?

Tags: mesos, dcos

When I get on the dcos github, I am bombarded with directories and files, where exactly can I find the source code of dcos??? I am assuming there should be a directory named src but I could not find it... Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

You can find it here https://github.com/dcos

DCOS is just a set of software that is configured to work together to deliver complete [Platform as a Service (PaaS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_as_a_service). Main parts of DCOS are:

- [Mesos](https://github.com/apache/mesos) - hearth of whole DCOS
- [Marathon](https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon) - scheduler that runs services on Mesos
- [Metronome](https://github.com/dcos/metronome) - scheduler for Jobs (could be replaced with Chronos)
- [Minuteman](https://github.com/dcos/minuteman) - A Distributed load balancer (L3)
- [Marathon-LB](https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon-lb) -  A service discovery & load balancing tool